# Get boolean value as a checkbox

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngx-datatable

I have a database. I want to display a table with all the data and get boolean values as a checkbox.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Value">
        <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
            <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="valueGroup.isAction"></mat-checkbox>
        </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

But I have an error

```
core.mjs:6485 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAction')
    at PeopleGroupsComponent_ng_template_15_Template (people-groups.component.html:20:27)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9618:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9484:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10609:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9508:1)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.mjs:10609:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9508:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9534:1)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.mjs:6485
```

TS code

```
  public peopleGroup: PeopleGroupModel = new PeopleGroupModel();

  dataSource: TableDataSource<PeopleGroupModel>;
  nameLookupControl: FormControl;
  constructor(
      injector: Injector,
  ) {
    this.dataSource = new TableDataSource(PeopleGroupModel, Endpoints.PEOPLE_GROUP_BASE, injector, true, 15);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nameLookupControl = new FormControl();
  }
```

Comment: what does your TS file look like? `valueGroup` is undefined.

Comment: i added ts code

Answer (score 0):

Just like [@marcusshep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3569921/marcusshep) said, the `valueGroup` is `undefined`. You should show more of your HTML code as it doesn't tell us how you get/assign value to `valueGroup`.

It is more likely you didn't assign the data to the `valueGroup` properly.

Comment: I added ts code

Comment: @TT90 Adding the TS code is a good start, but where did you **declare** and **assign** value to `valueGroup`?

Comment: Maybe you mean to use `value.isAction`? The `let-value="value"` assign and expose a variable called "value" which you can use.

Comment: @skouch2022 careful brother, this is not an answer.

Comment: @marcusshep yep, thanks. As a new user, we can't add a comment, but only answer. That's the only way we can communicate until we have enough reputation points, which I have enough now.

Comment: @skouch2022 I declare the model valueGroup: valueGroupModel;